# Keeping Lock across COMMIT AND CHAIN?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I am writing an application that processes jobs. A job does 2 things that are non-transactional: PartA and PartB. Both are idempotent.

A job has three statuses:

- Created
- PartA_Done
- PartB_Done

The logic looks something like this:

```
BEGIN;
let jobId = randomUUID
INSERT INTO jobs (id, status) VALUES (jobId, 'Created');
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
do partA in application code (make HTTP request)
UPDATE jobs SET status = 'PartA_Done' WHERE id=?
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
do partB in application code (make HTTP request)
UPDATE jobs SET status = 'PartB_Done' WHERE id=?
COMMIT;
```

PartA could succeed, but fail to update the `jobs` table. A retry cron job will retry to completion, `PartB_Done`.

If I were to add more than one cron job, i.e. running concurrently, there's a risk of the cron jobs doing duplicate work. In particular, both cron jobs could re-do `PartA`, `PartB` or both for the same job. I want to avoid that.

Is there any way for me to perform the `COMMIT`, while maintaining a `FOR UPDATE` lock in subsequent transactions on the new `jobs` row that I've added?

I thought that `COMMIT AND CHAIN` would work, but I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot keep a row lock across a commit. I have two ideas:

1. Add an additional column `processing_since` of type `timestamp with time zone`. The column is NULL when nobody works on the job. Whenever a process starts working on the job, it sets the column to `current_timestamp`, and when it completes a part, it does not only change `status` but also set `processing_since` to NULL.

   A job is up for grabs if `processing_since` is NULL or older than a certain time interval that is longer than it can possibly take to complete a part of the job. That way, the "lock" expires after a while.
2. Use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS). These locks can live longer than a transaction and don't cause problems with autovacuum. Unfortunately you are using UUIDs, otherwise you could have taken the `jobid` for the advisory lock. You could add another `bigint` column to the table just for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz! I enjoy reading your blog posts. For the latter 2 BEGIN/COMMIT, I would SELECT FOR UPDATE before doing the HTTP request?

Comment: No, why would you? Are you talking about the advisory locks?

Comment: Without that, two concurrent cron jobs could process the same job. No - talking about your option 1.

Comment: I wrote "A job is up for grabs if `processing_since` is NULL or older than a certain time interval that is longer than it can possibly take to complete a part of the job." That will make sure that no two workers grab the same job to work on.

Comment: Laurenz - what is to stop more than one cron worker from grabbing the same job? That's why I asked about `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. Perhaps `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` would be a good choice to avoid lock waits.